# Using Angular Child Component

Tags: angular, typescript, parent-child, angular-reactive-forms

I have a parent component, where it is a form, and inside I have validation, if the form is invalid, I pass data to a child component to render an alert on the screen informing the user that he needs to fill in all the fields.

This component is a child , as it is shared to be used in several other forms.

The issue is that I can even show the alert on the screen, passing the data, however, I can't use the setTimeout to hide it after a few seconds, due to it not recognizing the *ngIF, where I define true or false through it.

The interface I use to pass data from parent to child are:

```
export interface Alert{
  status: string;
  message: string;
  show: boolean;
}
```

In the parent component, when the save button is clicked, I carry out the validation below and pass the information to the child component.

```
informacoes: IAlert;

onSubmit(){
 if (!this.form.valid) {
     this.informacoes = {
          status: 'error',
          message: 'preencha todos os campos',
          show: true
      };
 }
```

I call child component as follows:

```
<app-child-alert *ngIf="informacoes" [info]="informacoes"></app-child-alert>
```

I need to put this *ngIf there in the tag, because if I don't put it, angular can't know when the information variable is filled in to activate the child component, that is, it doesn't activate when it is filled in in the validation of the form. And with that, there in the child component the *ngif starts to not work.

The first way I tried in the .ts of the child component looks like this:

```
 @Input() info: IAlert;
 

constructor() {
   
}

 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.fecharAlert();
  }


 fecharAlert() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.info.show= false;
    }, 3000);
  }
```

In the .HTML

```
<xxxx-status  type="{{info.status === 'error' ? 'error' : info.status}}" *ngIf="info.show">{{info.message}}</xxx-transaction-status>
```

The second way I tried in the .ts of the child component looks like this:

```
 @Input() informacoes: IAlert;
  open: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.open = true;
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.fecharAlert();
  }


  fecharAlert() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.open = false;
    }, 3000);
  }
```

```
<xxxx-status  type="{{info.status === 'error' ? 'error' : info.status}}" *ngIf="open">{{info.message}}</xxx-transaction-status>
```

So, how can I solve this problem, when in the validation of the form, trigger this child component and make it disappear too?

Comment: Have you considered using pre-built alerts like the ones in Angular Material. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: You second approach should work. Can you create a minimal, reproducible example online, for example in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: I'm reinventing the wheel, I think you didn't understand the context of the doubt. I already use a ready-made alert component from the company's lib.

Comment: How about just setting `this.informacoes = undefined` in the timeout?